# Google Maps / Fusion Table application misbehaving / losing data

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have two Google Maps using virtually the same code but behaving differently. Both query a Fusion Table to create layers (groups of markers) and both use a jQuery slider to trigger functions that set and unset the layers to / from the map. The sole difference between the two is the Fustion Table they query. [The one querying a small dataset](http://www.mos.org/energized/installations2.php) works as expected (all Fusion Table layers and their corresponding data points set and unset as expected). [The one querying about 3500 data points](http://www.mos.org/energized/installations.php) works as expected when setting / unsetting the first couple of layers (which aren't the layers with the most data points); then shows the wrong set of data points when setting the 2003-2006 layer (I verified that some 2005 data points are not in the 2003-2006 layer); then seems to continue working as expected for setting / unsetting the remaining layers.

I know this would seem to point to a glitch in the data somewhere but we've looked through it pretty thoroughly and can't find any issues there. I'm not violating the 5 layer limit (only one layer is set at a time) and can't find any limit on numbers of markers that can be added to a map.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Complete code below. Both versions are identical except for the Fusion Table IDs.

```
var map;
var infowindow;


function Initialize() {

    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(42,-71.5314);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: mapCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    layer2003 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2003'
        }
    });

    layer2004 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2004'
        }
    });

    layer2005 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2005'
        }
    });

    layer2006 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2006'
        }
    });

    layer2007 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2007'
        }
    });

    layer2008 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2008'
        }
    });

    layer2009 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2009'
        }
    });

    layer2010 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2010'
        }
    });

    layer2011 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'Geocode_Source',
            from: '2203337',
            where: 'Year <= 2011'
        }
    });


    layer2003.setMap(map);


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() > 12) {
            map.setZoom(12);
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        if (map.getZoom() < 8) {
            map.setZoom(8);
        }
    });

} //end function Initialize

//Set Fusion Table layers onto the map or to null, as appropriate
function set2003() {
    layer2003.setMap(map);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2004() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(map);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2005() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(map);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2006() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(map);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2007() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(map);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2008() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(map);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2009() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(map);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2010() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(map);
    layer2011.setMap(null);
}

function set2011() {
    layer2003.setMap(null);
    layer2004.setMap(null);
    layer2005.setMap(null);
    layer2006.setMap(null);
    layer2007.setMap(null);
    layer2008.setMap(null);
    layer2009.setMap(null);
    layer2010.setMap(null);
    layer2011.setMap(map);
}

function UpdateMap(){
    var value = $('#slider').slider('option', 'value');

    if (value==2003){set2003();}
    if (value==2004){set2004();}
    if (value==2005){set2005();}
    if (value==2006){set2006();}
    if (value==2007){set2007();}
    if (value==2008){set2008();}
    if (value==2009){set2009();}
    if (value==2010){set2010();}
    if (value==2011){set2011();}
}

$(function(){

    $('#slider').slider({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        animate: true,
        step: 1,
        min: 2003,
        max: 2011,
        change: function(event, ui){
            UpdateMap();
        }
    }); 
});
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the feature limit per tile: there is a limit of 500 markers per tile. Above 500, the markers are thinned. In your example, when going from 2005 to 2006, the number of markers per tile most likely jumps above 500, so some of the markers are thinned out, and some of these are markers from years less than 2005.

I hope this makes sense; let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks so much, Kathryn! Do you know if this marker limit per tile is a recent introduction to the API? (This is a new problem with an app that was working fine in March.) Is this documented anywhere? (I've searched for marker limits and came up empty; thought I'd re-read all the relevant documentation and didn't find anything.)

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't look like it's documented. We'll work on that. :) Can you also try one other thing? Convert the Location column from Location to Text then back to Location again. This sometimes helps fix issues with missing markers, but it might not help in this case.